# GLMNET prediction with intercept

Tags: r, prediction, intercept, glmnet

I have two questions about prediction using GLMNET - specifically about the intercept.

I made a small example of train data creation, GLMNET estimation and prediction on the train data (which I will later change to Test data):

```
# Train data creation
Train <- data.frame('x1'=runif(10), 'x2'=runif(10))
Train$y <- Train$x1-Train$x2+runif(10)
# From Train data frame to x and y matrix
y <- Train$y
x <- as.matrix(Train[,c('x1','x2')])
# Glmnet model
Model_El <- glmnet(x,y)
Cv_El <- cv.glmnet(x,y)
# Prediction
Test_Matrix <- model.matrix(~.-y,data=Train)[,-1]
Test_Matrix_Df <- data.frame(Test_Matrix)
Pred_El <- predict(Model_El,newx=Test_Matrix,s=Cv_El$lambda.min,type='response')
```

I want to have an intercept in the estimated formula. This code gives an error concerning the dimensions of the Test_Matrix matrix unless I remove the (Intercept) column of the matrix - as in

```
Test_Matrix <- model.matrix(~.-y,data=Train)[,-1]
```

My questions are:

- Is it the right way to do this in order to get the prediction - when I want the prediction formula to include the intercept?
- If it is the right way: Why do I have to remove the intercept in the matrix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to predict a model with intercept, you have to fit a model with intercept. Your code used model matrix `x <- as.matrix(Train[,c('x1','x2')])` which is intercept-free, therefore if you provide an intercept when using `predict`, you get an error.

You can do the following:

```
x <- model.matrix(y ~ ., Train)    ## model matrix with intercept
Model_El <- glmnet(x,y)
Cv_El <- cv.glmnet(x,y)
Test_Matrix <- model.matrix(y ~ ., Train)   ## prediction matrix with intercept
Pred_El <- predict(Model_El, newx = Test_Matrix, s = Cv_El$lambda.min, type='response')
```

Note, you don't have to do

```
model.matrix(~ . -y)
```

`model.matrix` will ignore the LHS of the formula, so it is legitimate to use

```
model.matrix(y ~ .)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it works! I missed the y ~ . syntax.

Comment: The output of this code is : 
coef(Cv_EL) = 
4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     1
(Intercept)  0.3311910
(Intercept)  .        
x1           1.3281315
x2          -0.8116813

What is with the intercept . term?

Answer (score 3):

The matrix `x` you were feeding into the `glmnet` function doesn't contain an intercept column. Therefore, you should respect this format when constructing your test matrix: i.e. just do `model.matrix(y ~ . - 1, data = Train)`.

By default, an intercept is fit in glmnet (see the `intercept` parameter in the glmnet function). Therefore, when you called `glmnet(x, y)`, you are technically doing `glmnet(x, y, intercept = T)`. Thus, even though your `x` matrix didn't have an intercept, one was fit for you.